# How to repeat a function with change some variables inside of the function? PYTHON 3.4

Tags: python, function, loops, python-3.4

i'm beginner and I would to like to know if there is some way to make a function that repeats itself changing valor the valor of some variables...

For example:

```
def example():
    box1.delete(0,END) #Here I would like to change the variable "box1" to "box2" and "box3"
    get1=box1.get() #Here I would like to change the variable "box1" to "box2" and "box3"
```

Well, I think that is all. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: simplified: add all boxes to a list, iterate over the list and do your delete and get from inside the for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, you would make `box` an argument to the function and call it repeatedly with all the boxes you want to operate on:

```
def example(box):
    box.delete(0, END)
    get = box.get()
    ...

for box in box1, box2, box3, box4:
    example(box)
```

if `example` actually returns something (e.g. the data that `box.get` returned), you can use a list comprehension.

```
boxes = (box1, box2, box3, box4)
data = [example(box) for box in boxes]
```

Now `data` is a list with one element from each element in `boxes`.

Comment: What about.. if I have diferent variables like this: def example(): box1.delete(0,END) #Here I would like to change the variable "box1" to "box2" and "box3" get1=box11.get() # #Here I would like to change the variable "box11" to "box22" and "box33" Sorry, I would like to know about how to do it with diferent variables in a function but I made a mistake explaining

Comment: when I try with "for box in box1, box2, box3, box4:
    example(box)"

It tell me "TypeError: example() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Comment: You didn't modify the signature of the `example` function.  Notice it is `def example(box): ...`, not `def example(): ...`

Comment: It works Thank you!
Could I make something similar if I have to change two or more variables?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a list of the boxes instead of having separate variable names for each. It makes your code more manageable and makes it easier to perform tasks on the boxes all at once.

For example:

```
boxes = []

#In your code where you create a box, instead of assigning it to a new variable as:
box12 = Box(...)

#just do
boxes.append(Box(...))
```

then you can easily do operations on the list by iteration through it or through list comprehension.

```
box_vals = [a.get() for a in boxes]
```

Comment: What about.. if I have diferent variables like this:

def example():
    box1.delete(0,END) #Here I would like to change the variable   "box1" to "box2" and "box3"
    get1=box11.get() # #Here I would like to change the variable   "box11" to "box22" and "box33"

Sorry, I would like to know about how to do it with diferent variables in a function but I made a mistake explaining